# Jar program works fine on Windows 7 machine, Windows 8 wont show custom images

Tags: java, image, jar, windows-8.1

OK, so I'm not sure what code you guys would need to see to help with this issue. let me be as complete as possible with my explanation. I have a program, made it into a jar (include the Images directory with all the custom images we use for the background and buttons.) . Then I put the jar into an installer (it's an executeable jar so just double click it to run on any computer that has Java). using NSIS. Installer works great installed it on my windows 7 machine which is where I did all the programming and has the JRE and JDK installed (1.7). Everything works like a champ! So stoked! A lot of our customers though have Windows 8, vista Mac etc.. So I need to test it on other windows machines to ensure it works. I tested first on a windows 8.1 machine sitting next to my windows 7 machine (wifes computer). I installed java using the installer (Yay!) and then installed the jar just like I did on my window 7 machine. Used the shortcut (and just the Jar itself) and the program comes up, but it doesn't show anything I used custom images on. IE: the background is an image as is the close minimize buttons, the buttons for install (it's an auto updater for wow addons) or even the finished buttons. None of that stuff displays and I can't figure out why. I tried changing  the images to use BufferedImage and imageIO no joy, Tried setting the lookandfeel to System look and feel. no help. Sure it shows the JProgress bar ont eh first card (using cardlayout), it shows the Username and Password JTextFields, and the AutoLogin checkbox on the login card, ad the Table and JTextField (for showing patch notes) on the addons card. but there is no backgournd, no buttons no nothing else. It even allows me to clickthru to stuff behind the updater as if the background and buttons did not even exist. But it only happens on windows 8, I tested after that on a vista machine and an XP machine. it works fine on vista, xp, and windows 7, but windows 8 machine it doesn't show any of the custom images (wich again are included in the Jar and I use absolute paths to get to them) So anyone have any clue what might be going on? What kind of code would you like to see to help troubleshoot this? What gets me is that it works fine on all windows machines except windows 8. *ARRRRRGH!!*
Please help!

OK, I did up this test cutting and pasting the code from my updater program to do it. Same problem occurs. Though I think I may have an idea of what the problem is now. even though I included the files of the images in the jar, it may be how I have them in the code, but I'm still not sure how to fix that.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;


//public static final String BG_IMAGE_PATH = "F:\\Java Programs\\Updater\\src\\com\\dynastyaddons\\updater\\images\\background.png";
private static JFrame rootFrame;

public TestBackgrounds() {
    rootFrame = new JFrame();
    SpringLayout rootLayout = new SpringLayout();

    // setup root frame
    rootFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    rootFrame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    rootFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    rootFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    rootFrame.setTitle("Dynasty Addons Updater");

    // add the background image
    JLabel bg = new JLabel();
    try {           
        Image myBGPic = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("background.png"));
        bg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myBGPic));
    } catch (IOException ignore) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ignore.getMessage());
    }
    bg.setLayout(rootLayout);
    rootFrame.add(bg);
    rootFrame.pack();
    rootFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    rootFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TestBackgrounds tb = new TestBackgrounds();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure I'd love to. How exactly do you expect me to do that? That's why I asked multiple times in the post what exactly I'd have to include here to show the problem off.

Comment: Got it put into a file, and tested with the same issues. Still not srue how to fix it, but thinkin it has something to do with the location of the image?

Comment: OK, so that worked to compile it, but the jar file wont run it. gonna start bangin my head on the wall soon. I'm editing my test file to show what I have in my program in the hopes that somehow it will work in my program the same as it does in the test.

Comment: OK, I just switched to forward slashes and that worked. :) Read another post about how it was a relative path and such and just moved the images into the folder with the class files (and the java files) and it all worked. now just have to fix the setIcon methods to change the buttons up when they need it and I'm home free. :)